# Using nbr value from incrementation

Tags: return, increment

I try to use new value from incremented variables.

```
package com.example.fps103;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int Nbr1, Nbr2, Total;
    Button AddOneNbr1, SupOneNbr1, AddOneNbr2, SupOneNbr2;
    TextView viewNbr1, viewNbr2, viewTotal;
```

The Total view left at 0...

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Total =Nbr1 + Nbr2;
        viewNbr1 = findViewById(R.id.textView_Nbr1);
        viewNbr2 = findViewById(R.id.textView_Nbr2);
        viewTotal = findViewById(R.id.textView_Total);
        AddOneNbr1 = findViewById(R.id.btnAddOneNbr1);
        AddOneNbr2 = findViewById(R.id.btnAddOneNbr2);
        SupOneNbr1 = findViewById(R.id.btnSupOneNbr1);
        SupOneNbr2 = findViewById(R.id.btnSupOneNbr2);
```

...but i increment Nbr1 and Nbr2 with buttons.

```
//Nbr1
        AddOneNbr1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Nbr1++;
                viewNbr1.setText(String.valueOf(Nbr1));
            }
        });
        SupOneNbr1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Nbr1--;
                viewNbr1.setText(String.valueOf(Nbr1));
            }
        });
//Nbr2
        AddOneNbr2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Nbr2++;
                viewNbr2.setText(String.valueOf(Nbr2));
            }
        });
        SupOneNbr2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Nbr2--;
                viewNbr2.setText(String.valueOf(Nbr2));
            }
        });


        viewNbr1.setText(String.valueOf(Nbr1));
        viewNbr2.setText(String.valueOf(Nbr2));
        viewTotal.setText(String.valueOf(Total));
    }
}
```

I suppose an value return problem for the 2 variables because if i initialize Nbr = 1, Total = 1 but not follow the increment from Nbr1 and 2.

return Nbr1; not work and appear with an red underlign in anywhere i put it in the code.